# mysql returns different value after 9 entries into a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mobile app that interacts with php instructions sitting on a linux server (php, mysql). A user is able to submit an item (in the app) by selecting a category, writing description, uploading a picture, price information and it all works fine as long as my 'category' table entries are 9 or less. As soon as I enter 10th entry into the table and select that category in the app, the submitted value defaults to 1 or 2 in the submission 'items' table. The 'category' table has just two columns: id and name

I am fairly new to programming but Here is the pc of code I think is responsible:

```
 function getCatagorysucessSel(result)
 {
    //window.localStorage.setItem("get_catagory",result);
    //placecatgrySelpage();     
    $('#select_choice_myitem').empty();     
    if(result.hasOwnProperty('categoryData'))
    {
        $('#select_choice_myitem').append(new Option(_('category'), '-1'));

        for(var i=0;i<result.categoryData.length;i++)
        {            
            $('#select_choice_myitem').append(new Option(_(result.categoryData[i].name), result.categoryData[i].id));           
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert("No category available");
    }
    $('#select_choice_myitem').find('option').each(function()
    {       
         if($(this).val()==-1)
         {
             $(this).attr('selected','selected');
         }
         else
         {
            $(this).removeAttr('selected','selected');
         }
    }); 
    //$("#select_choice_myitem [value='-1']").attr("selected","selected");      
    //$("#select_choice_myitem").val("-1").attr("selected", "selected");

    var activePage = $.mobile.activePage.attr("id");

    if (activePage == 'main_screen') 
    {
        //resetting submit item input fields
        window.localStorage.setItem("my_item_image",'');    
        $('#picture').attr('src','./themes/images/camera-icon.png')
        photo_imgeuri='./themes/images/camera-icon.png';
        $('.setting-form .ui-input-text').css({"background-color":"#fff"});
        $('.select-style').css({"background-color":"#fff"});
        $('#select_choice_myitem').trigger('create');           
        $('#textinput-hide_price').val('');             
        $('#textinput_hide_desc').val(''); 
        document.getElementById('submit_Sellpage').onclick = function() { saveItemSubmit(''); };
        $('#submit_Sellpage').css({"background-color":"#0099cb"});
        $('#submit_Sellpage').html(_('submit')); 

        pageNavigation('sellingPge');       
    }
    else
    {
        changeItemPage();
    }   
    $('#select_choice_myitem').selectmenu('refresh');
 }

 /*function placecatgrySelpage()
 {      
        $('#select_choice_myitem').empty();
            //$('#yourSelectBoxId').append(new Option('Select a catagory', 'null'));
            //var rresulta=window.localStorage.getItem("get_catagory");
            //console.log(rresulta);    
            //rresulta=JSON.parse(rresulta);    

}*/

function getCatagorySellPage()
{     
    if (document.getElementById('picture').value == null) {
        $('#textonImage').show();
    }
    //$('#textonImage2').show();
    //photo_imgeuri='';
    //$('#picture')[0].src = '#';
      //placecatgrySelpage();
      $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url:base_url+'services/getcategorylist.php',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    //data:JSON.stringify(login_json),
                    beforeSend:function(xhr){
                            showPageLoading();
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth()); 
                           //ActivityIndicator.show('Loading dictionary ....Please wait!');
                    },
                    complete:function(){
                        hidePageLoading();
                        //ActivityIndicator.hide();
                    },
                    success: getCatagorysucessSel,
                    error: error
                }); 
}
```

Here is php code residing on the server:

```js
$uid = userExists(isBlank('User id', $data->{"uid"}));
$sessionID = userSessionExists(isBlank('sessionID', $data->{"sessionID"}), $uid);
$cid = isBlank('Category id', $data->{"categoryid"});
$desc = isBlank('Description', $data->{"description"});
$price = isBlank('Price', $data->{"price"});
$countdown = isBlank('Countdown', $data->{"countdown"});
$picture = isBlank('Item picture', $data->{"picture"});
$lat = isBlank('Latitude', $data->{"latitude"});
$long = isBlank('Longitude', $data->{"longitude"});
$responseData = array();

// If itemid is not set, create new item and add to DB
if($data->{"itemid"} == '') {
 $insertQuery = sprintf("INSERT INTO items (itemid, cid, uid, description, price, countdown, picture, latitude, longitude, created) VALUES (NULL, %d, %d, '%s', '%f', '%s', '', '%s', '%s', '%s')", $cid, $uid, $desc, $price, $countdown, $lat, $long, time());
 mysql_query($insertQuery);
 $itemid = mysql_insert_id();

 if ($itemid != '') {
  $name = $itemid.'.jpg';
  file_put_contents("../files/itemspic/$name", base64_decode($picture));
  $picture = 'files/itemspic/'.$name;
  mysql_query("UPDATE items SET picture = '" . $picture . "' WHERE itemid = " .$itemid);
      
        $responseData['responseCode'] = '200';
  $responseData['responseStatus'] = 'success';
  $responseData['responseData'] = 'Item has been saved.';
 } else {
  $responseData['responseCode'] = '200';
  $responseData['responseStatus'] = 'error';
  $responseData['responseData'] = 'Unable to save item.';
 }
}
```

Comment: so u get **no** Input in database or wrong Input?

Comment: `"code I think is responsible"` - What makes you think that?  What debugging have you done?  Where specifically does the value first become incorrect?

Comment: The problem may be in the PHP code.

Comment: David, I have provided all the info I know at this point. You can try to be helpful. I spent quite a few hours understanding this problem. I still don't know why the submission defaults to 1 or 2 once I add more than 9 entries into the 'category' table. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please post your category and items table structure.

Comment: @KikiTheOne When I have nine or less rows in the 'category' table, the submission is done correctly and the id from the 'category' table is properly transferred into the 'items' table that records all submission values. However, when 'category' table grows to 10 entries or more, the id value in the 'items' table gets recorded as 1 or 2.

Comment: @NewtonSheesha mysql> select * from category;
+----+------------------+
| id | name             |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | auto             |
|  2 | baby sitting     |
|  3 | dating           |
|  4 | delivery service |
|  5 | home improvement |
|  6 | legal            |
|  7 | massage          |
|  8 | pets             |
|  9 | travel           |
| 10 | healthcare       |
+----+------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: @NewtonSheesha Table structure for table `category`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `category`
--

INSERT INTO `category` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'auto'),
(2, 'baby sitting'),
(3, 'dating'),
(4, 'delivery service'),
(5, 'home improvement'),
(6, 'legal'),
(7, 'massage'),
(8, 'pets'),
(9, 'travel'),
(10, 'healthcare');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `itemid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `countdown` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `expire_limit` varchar(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 => never expire, OR enter values in mintues',
  `created` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`itemid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=56 ;

Comment: @NewtonSheesha cid in the 'tems' table is where the id from the 'category' table is inserted

Comment: hmm try `default` instead of `null` @ `NULL, %d, %d, '%s', '%f', '%s', '', '%s', '%s', '%s'` . from part of ur Code i have no idea right now.

Comment: @KikiTheOne thanks, but it didn't work